# Java opc client application

Tags: java, opc

I am looking for some libraries and some examples to create an client OPC application in Java which could connect with opc server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java is a word and not an acronym

Comment: Did you use one of those libraries in production and do you have any comments/feedback on them?

Answer (score 9):

Have you checked out [OPC Client Programming with Java](http://www.opcconnect.com/java.php#javacom)?

They offer different links for this area:

- **Utgard - pure Java OPC library**

> [Utgard](http://openscada.org/projects/utgard/) is an open source project offering an OPC library written in
>   pure native Java, i.e. with no dependency on JNI or other DLLs. It is
>   licensed under the GPL.

- **JEasyOPC Client**

> Antonín Fischer's [Java OPC Client](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jeasyopc) is now greatly enhanced and hosted on SourceForge. It uses a JNI layer coded in
>   Delphi. Full source code (both Java and Delphi) is provided.

I think what you are looking for is **Utgard**, you can find **sample code** in the documentation sections, respectively in the project source code under documentation.

Comment: I have been in this website and there is: git://git.openscada.org/org.openscada.documentation.git   and this is one of the option by which I can get this samples. But my question is how to download it and get into my project, because it's git?

Comment: @user1519221 You need the source control management tool [git](http://git-scm.com/) with it you can get the code/documentation with `git clone [URL]`

Comment: we just finished a short tutorial to Utgard, have a look here: https://openscada.atlassian.net/wiki/display/OP/HowToStartWithUtgard

Comment: Notice that Utgard is not strictly GPL: "The Utgrad Project itself is licensed under the LGPL (unless noted otherwise).". Source: http://openscada.org/projects/utgard/

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. to go for the traditional OPC DCOM as suggested by platzhirsch. DCOM requires JNI and works only in Windows environments.
2. to go for OPC UA (Unified Architecture), which is the new version of OPC. OPC UA is available in pure Java and available in all Java SE 6 environments. OPC UA includes many advanced features, such as built-in security, information modeling, etc.

OPC UA makes you better future proof, since OPC UA is where all the development happens at the moment. You can also connect to OPC DCOM servers from OPC UA clients with the help of wrappers, such as the [UaGateway](http://www.unified-automation.com/uagateway.htm)

For OPC UA, I can suggest [Prosys OPC UA Java SDK](http://www.prosysopc.com/opc-ua-java-sdk.php) which is the most advanced option for Java at the moment (commercial, and yes, I am involved myself).

You can read more about OPC UA from [here](https://opcfoundation.org/about/what-is-opc/)

Comment: Is still Prosys for java maitained?

Comment: Yes, Prosys OPC UA SDK for Java is and will be maintained as usual and we just released version 4.0 with OPC UA 1.04 support. https://www.prosysopc.com/news/prosys-opc-ua-java-sdk-400-released/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some open source UPC UA implementations on GitHub:

- https://github.com/digitalpetri/ua-server-sdk
- https://github.com/digitalpetri/opc-ua-stack
- https://github.com/bcopy/opc-ua-stack

They're emerging and not complete, but if you're researching or prototyping, that the right way to start as opposed to full-featured commercial libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Implement OPC API in C++. Make it a DCOM object and running as a windows service.

You can connect to DCOM objects through J-Interop or JACOB both are JAVA-DCOM bridge.